# About GetMessage(..) in win32

Tags: winapi

I am a beginner on win32-platform, and there is some question about

```
BOOL GetMessage（LPMSG lpMsg，HWND hWnd，UINT wMsgFilterMin，UINT wMsgFilterMax) ;
```

I don't know what does it `wMsgFilterMin` and `wMsgFilterMax` means ? Thank you .....

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Ed Guiness: thanks for you help..can you give me a simple sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, keep in mind that GetMessage() only returns posted messages.  There are not many of them, mouse and keyboard messages, WM_INPUT, WM_TIMER, WM_PAINT, WM_QUIT.  Plus any that your own code delivers by calling PostMessage(), WM_USER+ messages.

Using the filter is pretty unusual, you normally pass 0 and 0 so nothing gets filtered.  You *might* consider passing WM_PAINT to flush all pending paint requests.  I can think of no good reason to ever filter mouse or keyboard messages.  But a definite use-case is your own posted messages.  Commonly used to deliver notifications from a worker thread to the UI thread for example.  You may want to filter them so they get processed before any of the regular messages.

Just put this in your back pocket.  You may have a use for it some day.

Answer (score 0):

range from wMsgFilterMin to wMsgFilterMax to filter.

message number: WM_XX, e.g. WM_CREATE (0x0001), WN_PAINT (0x000f), range from 0x0001 to 0x000f messages will be returned.

If you need only one kind of message, then make wMsgFilterMin equals wMsgFilterMax.

If no filtering (return all message types), then put both wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax 0.

Comment: yeah, but are you sure the range from WM_CREATE to WM_PAINT will all be filtered ? i.e its rank are regular ? if min is  Key_first and max is key_last ? how can i know the range's content..

Comment: @Tu_JianWu The filter includes all messages between min and max

Comment: @David Heffernan, thanks for help... Mmm,  if i want to filter two Message, but they are separate, how can i do it ?  And i think there is a another way to filter the message.. it's put the code in function as follow:  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) {if (msg.message == XXX) ....  }  can it work ?  and then what is the difference ?

Comment: 'while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) {if (msg.message == XXX)' is fine, and very common, as is a case switch on the message number.